# How to catch Drag and Drop event in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a `textbox`; there is decimal validation:

```
i.e User can enter only Numbers(upto two place decimal) and Dot.
```

Those are on **keypress** and **keyup**.

When number is entered directly, it works.

But when we drag and drop some alphabets in textbox 
then it does not work; till i click in textbox

What events are provided by Javascript which help me to detect whether values is **dragged and dropped** to textbox.

Comment: can you place code into jsfiddle, so we can more easily answer your question?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jdxn1Lmn/5/ - Drag a text in it and it is shown

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var oldVal = '';
    $('.myTexbox').keypress(function (event) {
        var a = isDecimalNumber(event, this)
        if (this.value.match("^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]{0,2}$"))
            oldVal = this.value;
        return a;
    });
     $('.myTexbox').keyup(function (event) {
        if (!this.value.match("^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]{0,2}$")) {
            $(this).val(oldVal);   
        }
    });
    $('.myTexbox').on("drop", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();  
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (!this.value.match("^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]{0,2}$")) {
            $(this).val(oldVal);   
        }
    });
});
function isDecimalNumber(eve, element) {
  var charCode = (eve.which) ? eve.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode == 44 || charCode == 46 || charCode == 8 || (charCode > 48 && charCode < 57))
     return true; 
  return false;
}
```

I think this is exactly what you need.

I tested the code in JS Fiddle and it works like expected.

Comment: Could you please tell me in layman language that What these two do? event.preventDefault();         event.stopPropagation();

Comment: Also it is not drag dropping correct value say 22222.22